# Cannot access array data in reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, undefined

When I'm trying to get data of getObjectives function, I have got undefined. I don't know where is the problem, in the function or in the code

The function GetObjectives()

```
export async function GetObjectives(docId) {
  try {
    const querySnapshot = await getDocs(collection(db, "users", "userIdNotAvailableForTheMoment", "documents", docId, "nodes"));
    const objectivesArray = [];

    querySnapshot.forEach(async (nodeDoc) => {
      const nodeId = nodeDoc.id;
      const objectivesQuerySnapshot = await getDocs(collection(db, "users", "userIdNotAvailableForTheMoment", "documents", docId, "nodes", nodeId, "objectives"));

      const objectivesData = objectivesQuerySnapshot.docs.map((objectiveDoc) => ({
        ...objectiveDoc.data(),
        id: objectiveDoc.id
      }));
      objectivesArray.push(objectivesData);
    });

    return objectivesArray;
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error during the recuperation of objectives : ', error);
    return null;
  }
}
```

An example of the code when I get data

```
GetObjectives(sortDocuments[parseInt(selectedDocument)].id, result[0].id)
  .then(async (result) => {
    console.log(result)
    console.log(result[0])
});
```

Reponses :
`console.log(result)` return what I want, however `console.log(result[0])` return undefined but I didn't know why

```
//console.log(result)
[
    [        
        {
            "parents": [],
            "childrens": [],
            "content": "value",
            "id": "VULpo5mPCc2kckLC9BCy",
            "title": "value"
        }
    ],
    [
        {
            "parents": [],
            "childrens": [],
            "content": "value",
            "id": "VULpo5mPCc2kckLC9BCy",
            "title": "value"
        }
    ]
]

//console.log(result[0])
Undefined
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. _"I don't know where is the problem"_: what steps have you taken to debug this? Part of development work is being able to narrow down bugs by testing your assumptions about data you're receiving and inspecting it step-by-step through your code. Note: `.then(async (result)` doesn't need to be `async`.

Comment: If you're indicating that `console.log(result)` observably logs an array with one or more elements to the console, and then `console.log(result[0])` observably logs `undefined` to the console, then I *strongly suspect* that you've made a false assumption in your debugging.  Can you provide a runnable [mcve] which demonstrates this behavior?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While I can't explain the console output, I strongly believe that part of the issue is that `GetObjectives()` is actually returning an array of promises rather than array of resolved objects. You can use [`Promise.all()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) to resolve the array of promises "in parallel". Does the following implementation of `GetObjectives()` fix your issue?

```js
export async function GetObjectives(docId) {
  try {
    const querySnapshot = await getDocs(collection(db, "users", "userIdNotAvailableForTheMoment", "documents", docId, "nodes"));

    const objectivesArray = querySnapshot.map(async (nodeDoc) => {
      const nodeId = nodeDoc.id;
      const objectivesQuerySnapshot = await getDocs(collection(db, "users", "userIdNotAvailableForTheMoment", "documents", docId, "nodes", nodeId, "objectives"));

      return objectivesQuerySnapshot.docs.map((objectiveDoc) => ({
        ...objectiveDoc.data(),
        id: objectiveDoc.id
      }));
    });

    return Promise.all(objectivesArray);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error during the recuperation of objectives : ', error);
    return null;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks it's work, the code

```
export async function GetObjectives(docId) {
  try {
    const querySnapshot = await getDocs(collection(db, "users", "userIdNotAvailableForTheMoment", "documents", docId, "nodes"));

    const objectivesArray = await Promise.all(querySnapshot.docs.map(async (nodeDoc) => {
      const nodeId = nodeDoc.id;
      const objectivesQuerySnapshot = await getDocs(collection(db, "users", "userIdNotAvailableForTheMoment", "documents", docId, "nodes", nodeId, "objectives"));

      return objectivesQuerySnapshot.docs.map((objectiveDoc) => ({
        ...objectiveDoc.data(),
        id: objectiveDoc.id
      }));
    }));

    return objectivesArray;
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error during the recuperation of objectives: ', error);
    return null;
  }
}
```